# webpack 2 remove additional info

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-2

After update to webpack 2, eslint output additional [info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8FFN.png)
how to remove this?

I try to change webpack stats config and eslint config, but its not help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not webpack that shows the additional info but a eslinter in the code editor or maybe there is something set up in the package.json like npm run lint -- --watch.